# django datetime to unix timestamp

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, unix-timestamp

my model

```
create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

how to get unix time from this field?

```
datetime.datetime.timestamp()
```

but I need int

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here create is a simple python datetime.datetime instance itself.

For python less than 2.x

You can do .

```
my_model = MyModel()
int(my_model.create.strftime('%s'))
```

For python 3.3+

You can just do

```
my_model = MyModel()
my_model.create.timestamp()
```